# How to bind two values into single values in ImageUrl using DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to bind two values into single values in ImageUrl using DataList.

Below is my bind ImageUrl code:

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' runat="server"
  Width="140" Height="120" />
```

Now ImageName output is coming like that.

```
Zahed.png
```

I need to output like below to bind Sno number also with ImageName.

```
1Zahed.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd use `Eval` because your Databinding is only one way

replace

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>'
```

with

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/SlideImages/" + Eval("ImageName") %>'
```